# How can I run a script in node_modules from a grunt task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I want to simplify how our test suites can be run from the command line. So I added the following [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) task to our `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {

  grunt.initConfig(
    {
      shell : {
        e2e : {
          command : "./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor_conf.js"
        }
      }
    }
  );

  grunt.loadNpmTasks( "grunt-shell" );

  grunt.registerTask( "e2e", ["shell:e2e"] );
};
```

When I run the task, I get the error:

> `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

All the examples I found for running shell commands ran binaries which were globally accessible, but I want to start the protractor binary that was installed locally.

I'm using bash on Windows, in case that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `protractor` as an argument to `node` to invoke it, like so:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {

  grunt.initConfig(
    {
      shell : {
        e2e : {
          command : "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor_conf.js"
        }
      }
    }
  );

  grunt.loadNpmTasks( "grunt-shell" );

  grunt.registerTask( "e2e", ["shell:e2e"] );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on OSX... but it should still apply for you?

I just provided an absolute path in my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        shell: {
            test: {
                // command: 'sh /Users/default/Sites/dev/test.sh'
                command: 'node /Users/default/Sites/dev/test.js'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell']);
};
```

Which provided me with the correct output.

Some other useful tasks for similar problems I came across:

grunt-execute, grunt-run

Comment: Hah! This helped me a lot. Sadly, I can't use an absolute path, because it will change depending on the workstation. But using `node` as the binary and then passing `protractor` as an argument works perfectly.